# Oracle create view from two tables

Tags: oracle, view

I have the following tables in Oracle 11g:

Table A

```
SITE_ID       SITE_NAME        VECTOR       .........MANY OTHER FIELDS

BN9032U850    REY DEL MAR      ENSENADA
BS2362U850    COSTA BAJA       LA PAZ
BS2601U850    LA PAZ           LA PAZ
BS2606U850    CONQUISTADORES   LA PAZ
BN2679U850    COAST CAST       TIJUANA
BN7116U850    PALACIO AZTECA   TIJUANA
```

Table B

```
SITE_ID       SITE_NAME             VECTOR       .........MANY OTHER FIELDS

BN9032        REY DEL MAR           (null)
BN9033        BRISAS DEL MAR        (null)
BS2601        CUMBRES DE LA PRESA   (null)
BN9038G850    REAL DEL CASTILLO     (null)
BS0014G850    SAN BRUNO             (null)
```

As you can see in both tables there are many other fields, but im only interested in the ones i wrote (SITE_ID,SITE_NAME,VECTOR).

What i want to achieve is to create a view with those three columns but with information from both tables.

But this view has to meet this condition:

- Take in mind only the first 6 characters from the SITE_ID field from both tables.

For example, the first record from Table A has this SITE_ID "BN9032U850", so if we substring the first 6 characters, the resulting SITE_ID would be "BN9032". But as you can see the first record from Table B has that same SITE_ID, so there would be a duplicate record.

If this happens, the record to be added to the view must be the one from Table A, not the one from Table B. In the end i want to achieve this output:

VIEW OUTPUT

```
SITE_ID   SITE_NAME           VECTOR

BN9032    REY DEL MAR         ENSENADA    --->Table A
BS2362    COSTA BAJA          LA PAZ      --->Table A
BS2601    LA PAZ              LA PAZ      --->Table A
BS2606    CONQUISTADORES      LA PAZ      --->Table A
BN2679    COAST CAST          TIJUANA     --->Table A
BN7116    PALACIO AZTECA      TIJUANA     --->Table A
BN9033    BRISAS DEL MAR      (null)      --->Table B
BN9038    REAL DEL CASTILLO   (null)      --->Table B
BS0014    SAN BRUNO           (null)      --->Table B
```

I've been working on it with this sentence but something seems to be wrong.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) SITE_ID,SITE_NAME, VECTOR FROM TABLE_A
WHERE(SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6)) NOT IN
(SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) FROM TABLE_B)
UNION
SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) SITE_ID,SITE_NAME, VECTOR FROM TABLE_B
WHERE(SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6)) NOT IN
(SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) FROM TABLE_A);
```

I hope you can help me with some example code to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first half of your UNION doesn't want the NOT IN clause:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) SITE_ID,SITE_NAME, VECTOR
  FROM TABLE_A
UNION
SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) SITE_ID,SITE_NAME, VECTOR
  FROM TABLE_B
 WHERE(SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6)) NOT IN (SELECT SUBSTR(SITE_ID,1,6) FROM TABLE_A);
```

Everything from Table_A plus those rows in Table_B not found in Table_A.

Answer (score 0):

As you want everything in `table_A` that is not in `table_B` I would use a join in the second condition. You should have a functional index on `substr(site_id,1,6)` on both tables , unique if possible, to speed this up.

This is functionally similar to [Jonathan Leffler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9224315/458741) but it makes more explicit the fact that if you're selecting everything from this view then you will full scan and full index scan `table_A` - assuming the index suggested is in place. It also makes it more explicit that if you go in on the index then you will only do an index range / unique scan on both tables.

```
select substr(site_id,1,6), as site_id ,site_name, vector
  from table_a
 union
select substr(site_id,1,6), as site_id ,site_name, vector
  from table_b b
  left outer join table_a a
    on substr(b.site_id,1,6) = substr(a.site_id,1,6)
 where a.site_id is null
```